# Concat 3 textfields forming a birthday

Tags: flutter, date, validation, dialog

[3 Textfields are aligned in a row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkbpl.jpg)

Awaiting for inputs dd mm yyyy respectively.
On page open, Autofocus on 1st textfield, as input hits 2 digits, autofocus goes to 2nd textfield. As input hits 2 digits, autofocus goes to last textfield with 4 digits.
Users don't need to input '/' or '-'. Only the dates will do.

[Age Dialog formed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asLGP.jpg)

Does anyone know how to create such a textfield combination for birthdates? Such that when user presses 'Next' Button, a dialog forms which asks user to confirm his/her age?

(meaning that the input from the 3 textfields were saved as birthdates and the output is (today's current date - date input) = age.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to create one `FocusNode` for each `TextField`, then in the validator of your TextFields use a `birthdayMonthFocusNode.requestFocus()`.

You can check more on:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus

Then, you must do a little logic when the user hit the "Next" button.
You concatenate all the `TextEditingController().text` for each TextFields and using a `DateTime.tryParse()` you should end with the birthday DateTime of your user in no time.

Comment: thanks! I managed to to get it and the age as well. But I have another question. 
With the age in a stateless widget, how do I then pass the value to another widget to use?
I tried storing it as code: 
'return age = UserAge.age;  '

I have a class outside this stateless widget, code 
'class UserAge with ChangeNotifier {
  static int age;
  notifyListeners();
}
'

And then I tried to pass code 'age' into a ternary operator in another stateless widget with no avail. The value is null.

Comment: I didn't quite understand, can you provide code with a Codepen or a github gist ? @VegetaSaiyan

Comment: here you go: https://gist.github.com/vegeta-ssaiyan/f57676149ee4cb1e9a8d0064e46dc9d9

I'm sorry it's long. In general, my query is storing the data @ line 286 to the class @ line 296. to be used globally or eg @ line 310.

Comment: You will have to use some kind of state management to do this, maybe use a Provider or my personal favorite, Stacked